# Can you compute this integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to integrate
$$
\int_0^{\infty}dx\,e^{-ax}\frac{1-(2x)^b}{1-2x}
$$
where $a,b>0$. Any ideas about how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Possibly factor into a series:
$$
1-z^b = (1-z)\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} z^k
$$

Then your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x e^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} (2x)^k
$$
which you can compute as the sum of the integrals since the sum is finite...

Comment: $b$ need not be a natural number.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt i agree but this will give you an approach for natural numbers, and seeing the form of the answer, i would try to speculate that it looks the same for reals -- but that would need proof, of course...

Comment: You could try an infinite series of Gamma functions.

Comment: @gt6989b thanks for the input but what I am interested in is the $b$ non integer case

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus there does not seem to be a wealth of suggestions for your question yet -- why not try to see what the answer for an integer $b$ is and hope to prove that real $b$ has the same form?

Comment: @gt6989b I have done that, and the answer you get gives you a function that has an imaginary part for some values of $b$, which shouldn't be the case since the result should be real, so you cannot extrapolate from the integer case...

Comment: Using this suggestion I found $$-{a^{b+1}-2^{b+1}\over a-2}$$